# qt Android app: Child widgets appears in parent even hide is called

Tags: qt, qt-necessitas

I am having a main widget and multiple child widgets to show.

I add all child widgets to the main widget layout and call show of only one child and hide others.

In windows PC this works fine. But in android the child widget appears even if hide is invoked. Can anyone suggest where I'm wrong.

```
#include "mainframe.h"
#include "ui_mainframe.h"

MainFrame::MainFrame(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainFrame)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_pMainLayout   = ui->gridLayout;
    initialize();
}

MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainFrame::initialize()
{
    m_pStartupScreen = new StartupScreen(this);
    m_pSystemScreen  = new SystemScreen(this);

    m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pStartupScreen);
    m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pSystemScreen);

    connect(m_pStartupScreen, SIGNAL(reportsButtonClick()),
            this, SLOT(handleUserOptionReports()));
    connect(m_pStartupScreen, SIGNAL(systemButtonClick()),
            this, SLOT(handleUserOptionSystem()));
    connect(m_pStartupScreen, SIGNAL(salesButtonClick()),
            this, SLOT(handleUserOptionSales()));

    m_pSystemScreen->hide();
    m_pStartupScreen->show();

    connect(m_pSystemScreen, SIGNAL(closeInvoked()), m_pStartupScreen, SLOT(show()));
}
```

`m_pStartupScreen` and `m_pSystemScreen` appears in android devices, ie, both child widgets appears overlapped.

Comment: Could you please also try 5.3.0, not just Qt 4?

Comment: Then why is it tagged as qt-necessitas?

Comment: Pl tell me if I am wrong. I understand qt-necessitas as android app developed using Qt.

Comment: Qt necessitas is for Qt 4.